# Report verbosity : Request and answer no longer in report with 0.9.0

Tags: karate

Since switching to the version 0.9.0 of karate, I no longer have access to the html requests and responses in the cucumber-html-report, which was placed after each

```
* When method {get|post|delete}
```

I checked the release information, but using the command below didn't solve my problem.

```
* configure report = { showLog: true, showAllSteps: true }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on a clean project. I'm working on finding the parameters that cause the problem. But I found another problem with the new version : when not using @parallel=false, theHTTP requests and answers are not displayed in the correct scenario. One scenario will have multiple requests, some will be empty, some will only have the answer.

Comment: adrien - thanks, you indeed found an issue. just fixed it - can you validate this once: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The report now lacks this information when the logger level (in logback-test.xml) is INFO

```
    <logger name="com.intuit" level="DEBUG"/>
```

But the bug with parallel scenarios reports is still present.